# Accessing iframe.contentWindow.document not working using postMessage()

Tags: javascript, same-origin-policy, postmessage

My goal is to add css to the iframe content from the parent page. I have two different domains one rendering an iframe from the other, I'm using `postMessage` to bypass the `same-origin` policy issue however this doesn't seem to work as expected. When I try to `console.log(iframe.contentWindow)` I get an error in the console `Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://parent.domain.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.`

iframe

```
<iframe
        sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups allow-forms"
        src="https://domain.with.iframe.content"
        width="100%"
        frameBorder="0"
        id="iframe-1"
    ></iframe>
```

Page with iframe.

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
        var iframe = document.getElementById("iframe-1");
        console.log(e)
        console.log(e.origin)
        console.log(iframe)
        console.log(iframe.contentWindow)
    }, false);
</script>
```

Page that I'm iframing.

```
<script>
    var body = document.body
    body.onload = function resize() {
        parent.postMessage(["hey"], "*");
    }
</script>
</script>
```

From the console I can see that the `message` event listener is running, however this line `console.log(iframe.contentWindow)` throws the error. Any help will be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You can't do this, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame so you'll need to pass the data you need back and forth with postMessage

Comment: @Milton my goal is to be able to add css to the iframe content from the parent page, how would suggest going about that. Thanks.

Comment: It depends on how you get the CSS but assuming you have it as a string, you could send that string to the iframe using postMessage. Inside the iframe you could create a style tag, set the innerHTML of that tag to the CSS string and append it to the document head. Like in this article under Global Styles https://dev.to/karataev/set-css-styles-with-javascript-3nl5

Comment: Thanks @Milton it worked, if you could add it as an answer that would be awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding an answer from my comments:
You can't access `iframe.contentWindow` from the parent frame, see [SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame)
So you'll need to pass the CSS you need back and forth with `postMessage`.

Depending on how you get the CSS but assuming you have it as a string, you could send that string to the iframe using `postMessage`. Inside the iframe you could create a style tag, set the innerHTML of that tag to the CSS string and append it to the document head. Like in this article under Global Styles https://dev.to/karataev/set-css-styles-with-javascript-3nl5